# I can connect to a computer, but can't open a service running on it?

Tags: networking, hosting

I know almost nothing about networking but maybe someone can help me solve this problem.

Computer A is running a thing on port 4444
Computer B is running a thing on port 4444

**If I am on computer A**
 - I can ping computer B (both by IP address and name)
 - I can remote into computer B
 - *I cannot open http://computerB.domain.com:4444/service !!!*

However, if I am remoted into computer B, I can open everything just fine on that machine (the service running on computer A, and computer B, ping successfully, whatever).

I have disabled the firewall on both computers, but must be getting blocked by something else.  Any ideas?

Comment: It just sounds like the service isn't configured to allow remove connection. Specifics might be helpful.  I know MySQL has to specifically configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: I am running selenium grid on both computers.  I guess the problem is just that I can't connect to the grid by opening http://computerB.domain.com:4444/service even though I seem to be able to connect to the machine in every other way.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking this question wrong.. It seems that computer B can connect to everything on computer A flawlessly... but going the other way seems to be blocked by something.  Idk

Comment: Usually you have one hub (port 4444) and multiple nodes (port 5555).

Comment: Yeah, I have one instance of Hub / Nodes running on computer A, and another on computer B.  Computer B can connect to the one on computer A.. computer A cannot connect to the one on computer B.  does that make more sense?